# How to replicate 'Google Analytics Settings' variable in GA4 tag setup?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

With UA it is possible to declare a variable of type 'Google Analytics Settings' and in this variable we can set the GA container ID + all fields we want to set + all custom dimensions we want to set. This allow us to do this configuration only once, and then any tag that uses this configuration always sets these global fields and dimensions. This is for example useful for pushing the user ID.

With GA4 this variable type doesn't seem to be supported. We are only allowed to use Tags and on each Tag the GA4 container ID needs to be set individually as well as all the fields and custom dimensions. This means that for every tag that we have we need to remember to set all fields and dimensions each time.

I have over 100 Tags in GTM that I am converting to GA4 and this is becoming a real pain. I can already see the issues with maintanance as there is no single source for this configuration and if I later decide I want to add  a new custom dimension I will have to add it to all 100 fields, where in UA I could have justed edited the variable and it affected all the 100 tags automatically.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to set global custom dimensions and fields in GTM when working with GA4 container?

UA variable configuration allowing for global fields and dimensions:
[image]

GA4 tag configuration requiring individual fields config per tag
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using the GTM `Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration` tag to set values that persist during the lifetime of the pageload, re-executing it whenever a *global* parameter changes.

In order to not send multiple `page_view` events, you need to disable page view tracking in the config tag and create a separate `page_view` event tag.

[image]

Google writes:

> By updating the config command in the global site tag, you can set parameter values for every event on a page. For example, to change the page title, add the page_title parameter to your config command.

This should be what's happening in the background when calling the GTM Config Tag.

If you want the global fields to also affect other Measurement IDs, you can call `gtag.set`:

> If you configure multiple properties on a page, use the set command so that all measurement IDs inherit the properties. Place the set command above the config command so the values are passed with pageviews.

```
gtag('set', {
  'random_session_id': '143b9fda',
});
```

You might have use a Custom HTML Tag for this and set it as a `Setup Tag` for the GA4 Config Tag.

(Ref.: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11396839?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So you are saying that if I add a GTM TAG that is Custom HTML type and has the gtag('set'....) javascript in there, I do not have to add the 'Fields to Set' configuration to any of the tags in GTM, as long as I make sure that the Custom HTML tag is fired first?

Comment: If you want the fields to just persist for GA4, setting the variables in the "Config" tag as described above is enough. The fields set will persist for all GA4 events sent on the current page. If I understand Google's docs correctly, doing what you just described (`gtag.set`) would also persist the values but not just for one GA4 measurement id, but for all Google Tools on the page that use gtag, for example the Google Conversion Tags.

Comment: Allright, thank you! Guess we will have to try it and review it to be 100% sure, but thank you so much for pointing me in a direction that seems worth exploring <3 I've marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: You're welcome! I am also in the process of figuring out GA4. If you have any new insights regarding this topic, feel free to leave another comment! :-)