# Keeping user properties between events (Google Tag Manager, Google Analytics 4)

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have a question about user properties in Google Analytics 4.

I created 2 events:
The first one is called custom_session_start and it is triggered every time new session started.
The second is called UI_Interaction which is event that triggers every time that the user is clicking on something in the website.

The custom_session_start has some user properties and event parameters his specific tag in GTM.
The UI_Interaction event has only event parameters in his specific Tag.

From what I know the user property should be save unless I change it manually, so if I created some user properties in custom_session_start they also should be appear in UI_Interaction.
However, when I create a report in GA4 the user properties are only set in every custom_session_start event and they are empty in UI_Interaction event.

Is there a way to keep them also when the UI_Interaction occurs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747142/how-to-replicate-google-analytics-settings-variable-in-ga4-tag-setup/71765407#71765407